# Loading data by clicking on a table element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have an API that sends me some data. And now I'm making AngularJS client for this API.

So, basically, I have a table of elements. And every element in the table has **ui-sref** link to the standard **element.html** page. At the same time every element has **ng-click** that triggers the function that gets data with this particular id and putting it at **$scope.data** variable. The **element.html** page getting data from **$scope.data** and showing it.

And as I can get it. Loading data from API takes more time them loading the page, so it's not showing proper data.

So I'm really new to JS and AngularJS. Can anyone give me some help on that?)

service.js

```
var service = angular.module('service', ['datatables']);

service.controller('DaraController', ['$http', '$scope', function ($http, $scope) {
$scope.data;
var configAuth = {
        headers : {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
    };
this.getData = function (id) {
        $http.get(urlAPI + '/data/' + id, configAuth).then(
            function success(response) {$scope.data = response.data;},
            function error(data) {console.log(data);}
        );
    };
  }]);
```

dataDashboard.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="grapes">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Data table</title>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-include="'header.html'"></div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div ng-include="'sidebar.html'"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
            <h1 class="page-header">Data</h1>
        <div class="table-responsive" ng-controller="DataController as roleController">
                <table datatable="ng" class="table table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="data in dataController.datas()">
                        <td>{{data.id}}</td>
                    <td><a ui-sref="element" ng-click="dataController.getData(data.id)">{{data.name}}</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

element.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="grapes">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body class="container">

<div ng-include="'header.html'"></div>
<div ng-include="'sidebar.html'"></div>

<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
    <div class="table-responsive" ng-controller="dataController as dataController">
        <div>
            <h1 class="sub-header">{{data.id}}. {{data.name}}</h1>
            <div ng-repeat="operation in data.operations">
                <p> - {{operation.name}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**UPD:** Maybe there is a way to hold on with page loading until function is done getting data?

app.js

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module('app',['service', 'ui.router']);

app.controller('AppController', function () {

});

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('data', {
            templateUrl: 'dataDashboard.html'
        })
        .state('element', {
            templateUrl: 'element.html'
        })
});

})();
```

Comment: Post the code for your routing

Comment: @Daniel_L routing is in the app.js. done.

Comment: Might be a race condition between `ui-sref` and `ng-click` receiving the same event at the same time. Instead of `ui-sref` use `$state.go` in your `ng-click` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure that your data is loaded when you're displaying element.html page, you can use `$state.go()` methods instead of ui-sref attribute.

By using this methods directly like:

```
function success(response) {
    $scope.data = response.data;
    $state.go('element');
}
```

it should work.
(in that case don't forget to inject `$state` in your controller)

Comment: niceeee. Now I can see that data is loading before the **element.html** page, which is great, but it's still doesn't show up;//

Comment: yeah, I got why is this happening. I'm saving data in variable of controller. But going to another page reloading this controller and discarding any previous savings. Any ideas?)

Comment: yep, actually I see 2 way to do this:
- change your state conf with: 
`.state('element', {
    url: '/element/:id',
    templateUrl: 'element.html'
})`
that way you'll be able to do your "getData" function in your dataController, but maybe you'll have to display a loader to show that you're waiting for server data...
- another solution could be by passing data to a common service. For that you can find a lot of articles, but here's one I used long time ago: https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/services

Comment: For the first solution, you could check the state "resolve" attribute, it should be a bit better than handle the whole "getData" function in your dataController. Depends if your really want data loaded before page change, or if an async display is fine enough...